# Guides for adding 64-bit support to a KMDF driver

Tags: documentation, 64-bit, driver, kmdf

Are there any guides or documentation for adding 64-bit support to a KMDF driver? I have a good set of links for WDM drivers, but it would be nice to see a KMDF-specific guide showing what KMDF handles for you and what the driver needs to handle.

**EDIT:** Here are the links I have so far:
[Programming Issues for 64-bit Drivers (Windows Driver Kit)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff559923%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
[64-bit Guidelines](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/64bitguide.mspx)
[Checklist for 64-bit Microsoft Windows Drivers](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/kernel/64bit_chklist.mspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues are exactly the same, whether you use KMDF or WDM.

- You need to make sure that your driver contains no code that assumes that pointers or handles are the same size as integers.
- You need to use the DMA functions, not assuming that your device can address all of memory.
- You need to recompile and test.
- You need to avoid floating point code in drivers.